# Angular 2.2.0 Injection migrated from RC5 => switched injections

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I have an amazing issue since I migrate my code from Angular 2 RC5 to 2.2.0. I inject service into other services like that :

```
  constructor(_http:Http,
          _cachingServices:CachingServices,
          _globalServices:GlobalServices,
          _dataServices:DataServices,
          _notificationServices:NotificationServices)
```

That was working fine in RC5 but now, with 2.2.0 version, the injections are mixed! The following code :

```
  // Constructor
  constructor(_http:Http,
          _cachingServices:CachingServices,
          _globalServices:GlobalServices,
          _dataServices:DataServices,
          _notificationServices:NotificationServices){

console.debug(this.className + " param globalServices  => ",_globalServices);
console.debug(this.className + " param cachingServices => ",_cachingServices);
console.debug(this.className + " param dataServices => ",_dataServices);
console.debug(this.className + " param notificationServices => ",_notificationServices);

 }
```

Give me the following result :

```
  TranslateServices param globalServices  =>  DataServices {connectionStrings: Object, mode: "dev", magicServices: MagicServices, apiURL: "http://127.0.0.1/api.php", baseURL: "http://localhost:3000"}
  TranslateServices param cachingServices =>  CachingServices {expiration: EventEmitter, cacheduration: 400000}
  TranslateServices param dataServices =>  NotificationServices {notification: EventEmitter, types: Object, notification_one_like_per_day: "notification_one_like_per_day", notification_one_message_per_day: "notification_one_message_per_day", notification_thanks_for_message: "notification_thanks_for_message"…}
  TranslateServices param notificationServices =>  GlobalServices {mode: "dev", apiURL: "http://127.0.0.1/api.php", baseURL: "http://localhost:3000"}
```

ERROR => Services references are mixed !
I've searched for a while without any start of answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker? I guess this is some problem with your local setup because this usually just works.

Comment: I am full of good will but it would take me a lot of time. If I could avoid that would be good. :'(

Comment: + If I switch declarations in the constructor, the result is not the same.

Comment: Do you know what references a you  using?

Comment: What do you mean by "references" ? Values from the package.json ? I use the latest angular2-quickstart config.

Comment: Even if I delete all js files and I recompile, the result stay the same. I've also tryed to rebuild a new project from scratch => same issue.

Comment: I have found the problem but I can't explain it. That frighten me a little bit :/. I answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG ! what a suspicious issue. My solution have several services. Each of those reference another services **but there is no cyclic reference**.

Let's take two services:
**translate.services.ts**

```
  export class TranslateServices extends BaseServices {

  // Constructor
  constructor(_http:Http,
              _globalServices:GlobalServices,
              _cachingServices:CachingServices,
              _dataServices:DataServices,
              _notificationServices:NotificationServices,
              _ipServices:IPServices,
              _configurationServices:ConfigurationServices){
  }
}
```

and **user.services.ts**

```
export class UserServices extends BaseServices {

  constructor(_http:Http,
              _globalServices:GlobalServices,
              _cachingServices:CachingServices,
              _dataServices:DataServices,
              _notificationServices:NotificationServices,
              _ipServices:IPServices,
              _cookieServices:CookieServices) {
  }
}
```

We can see that the **translate.services** inject **configuration.services** and **user.services** inject **cookie.services**.

In my case, if translate.services is initialized first, the following commands :

```
    console.debug("TranslateServices _configurationServices => ",_configurationServices);
    console.debug("UserServices _cookieServices => ",_cookieServices);
```

Will give the following output :

```
TranslateServices _configurationServices => ConfigurationServices
UserServices _cookieServices => ConfigurationServices
```

And if user.services is initialized first, the same commands :

```
    console.debug("TranslateServices _configurationServices => ",_configurationServices);
    console.debug("UserServices _cookieServices => ",_cookieServices);
```

Will give the following output :

```
TranslateServices _configurationServices => CookieServices
UserServices _cookieServices => CookieServices
```

The position of the paramaters **_cookieServices** and **_configurationServices** seems to have an importance even if they are in two differents services.

To handle that issue, I have to give the same signature at the boths services :

```
    export class TranslateServices extends BaseServices {

  constructor(_http:Http,
              _globalServices:GlobalServices,
              _cachingServices:CachingServices,
              _dataServices:DataServices,
              _notificationServices:NotificationServices,
              _ipServices:IPServices,
              _configurationServices:ConfigurationServices
              _cookieServices:CookieServices) {
  }
}

export class UserServices extends BaseServices {

  constructor(_http:Http,
              _globalServices:GlobalServices,
              _cachingServices:CachingServices,
              _dataServices:DataServices,
              _notificationServices:NotificationServices,
              _ipServices:IPServices,
              _configurationServices:ConfigurationServices
              _cookieServices:CookieServices) {
  }
}
```

That seems not to be a normal behavior. I struggled a lot to find the begining of an explanation. Hope that bug will be corrected in an incomming version.

If someone can give me more explanations, I want.

Comment: Please remove all these `@Inject()` they are redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the trick ;) My code is passed throught alpha47,RC1,RC2,RC5,2.2.0 and I haven't yet taken all new patterns into account.

Comment: The issue you're describing seems to be related to inheritance (`BaseService`). Angular2 still doesn't work well with inheritance. They're working on it though.

Comment: I am thinking the same too. But that wasn't a problem with the RC5. Some modifications has maybe been introduced on that such a standard pattern as the inheritance. I'm so surprized that something so basic, introduced in the oldest programming languages 30 years ago, doesn't working as a charm.

Comment: I don't think TS is 30 years old and Angular2 uses the newest features of it.

Comment: Anders Hejlsberg was supervising the development of TS. He as created the first programming language with inheritance : Turbo Pascal in 1984. But I encourage them to improve that fascinating language wich break the frontiers between web and applications :)

Comment: DI is not a language feature and TypeScript depends on what JS can carry and JS is just becoming a programming language. That it was introduced 30 years ago doesn't mean much. It still has to carry the burden of it's inheritance.